# Can't throw loot bag in Payday 2 Crime Wave edition Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, payday-2

This is a very annoying bug in the game.  It seems to occur randomly, usually in games I am **not** hosting.  My HUD displays that I am carrying a loot bag, but I cannot throw it.

Because of this, I cannot pick up anymore bags, and I am rendered virtually useless. I also happened to notice that while this is occurring, my grenades disappear when thrown (not as annoying, but just an observation).  It is an extremely frustrating bug since throwing loot bags is one of the main mechanics of the game. It's also worsened by the fact that depending on what's in the bag, you can no longer sprint.

The only "fix" for this bug I know of is quitting the game and having the host invite me back in.  However, I believe joining in on a game and completing it doesn't count as a win (you still get XP and money, but the game doesn't count it as a win on whatever difficulty you are on for that level).

Does anyone know what causes this bug so I can try to avoid it? Better yet, is there a way to fix it without quitting out?

Answer (score 1):

There is another fix but it's not very practical. You have to go into custody and be free'd.

Answer (score 1):

You probably threw the coke away while healing with the doctor's bag. Go back to the place where you threw your doctor's bag and there you'll find the coke that you have to throw into the helicopter. This happened to me too.

Comment: Too late now for this.  I think the glitch may have been patched at this point.